# How do you set encrypted Travis env variables in docker?

Tags: deployment, docker, travis-ci, ansible

In writing my deployment script, I want to set a git checkout url that I want to be secret. I want to create a Travis job to test out my playbook. The easiest approach that I can think of now is by setting my global_vars to look for an env variable say `DEPLOYMENT_GIT_URL`. I then encrypt this env variable in `travis` and pass it to `docker exec` when I am building the docker image to test against my playbook.

Question:

1. Can I pass my encrypted Travis variable to the instance via `docker exec` ? Something like `sudo docker exec ... export DEPLOYMENT_GIT_URL=$TRAVIS_ENV ansible-playbook -i ....`
2. While this seems the simplest way to do it, appreciate comments on this method.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to check out ansible-vault for storing secrets.

Answer (score -1):

You can [pass variables directly to Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line). If you want nested or complex variables, use a JSON string.

```
docker exec <container> ansible-playbook -e GITURL="$GITURL" whatever.yml
```

As gogstad mentions, Ansible has the facility to manage secrets via [`ansible-vault`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html). Unless this URL is information that Travis needs to be the source of, it might be easier storing it directly in Ansible. Otherwise `openssl` can manage the secret:

```
secret=$(echo -n "yourdata" | openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -k 'passpasspass')
echo $secret | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -k 'passpasspass'
```

If you really want to pass the data with an environment variable you would need to do that at container creation with `docker run` and  [`-e`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)

```
docker run -e GITURL="what" busybox sh -c 'echo $GITURL'
```

Comment: How would you adapt the whole setup you mentioned above to Travis ?